# jQuery .each deep selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am traversing a complex DOM, I have a repetitive html structure

I am using the each feature in jQuery

```
$('.row').each(function (index, object) {
   $(object).find('label[for="duedate"] > .input-group > input:first').text();
}
```

I am trying to use the above code to start the traversal but i am getting undefined in the results.

A sample of my html is as follows

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="form-group ml-sm mr-sm"> 
        <label class="control-label" for="duedate">Due Date</label> 
        <div class="input-group"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
            </span> 
            <input "type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control" readonly="readonly" required> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I wanted to traverse through each line of html looking for specific classes and elements until i hit the input element and then retrieve the text.

Can anyone suggest the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you put an id on the input, you can just do $('#id').  Traversing the DOM is very inefficient.

Comment: `input` elements don't have any text. Do you mean `.val()`?

Comment: There's no `object-container` in your HTML, and `form-group` is not a child of `label`.

Comment: Is their a way to search for ids that start with a specific sequence of letters?

Comment: Try removing the ">" symbols and switching "text()" to "val()".

Comment: yep sorry my bad object-container is  supposed to be row, i copied and pasted some code from my project, post updated.

Comment: removed the ">" and updated the text to val but i still receive undefined when alert(text);

Comment: You also don't need `object` when you can use `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$('.object-container  label[for="duedate"]').parent(".form-group").find("input:text").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    // do something with text
});
```

`.form-group` is the parent of `label`, but your selector had it as the child. And `input:text` is not a child of `label`, it's a descendant of `.form-group`.

And to get the input in a text field, you use `.val()`. `.text()` is for the text content of an HTML node.